# Wifi problem in ubuntu using macbook pro when it restart

Tags: wireless, reboot, macbook-pro

I was read that subject :
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2011756

and i follow it step by step in the page n 1 , then i was connect but after i restart my macbook again , i was lost the wifi connection.i dont know why or whats the problem exactly.

every time I run this command:

```
dmesg | grep -e b43 -e bcma
```

I get this output:

```
[ 2012.769684] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[ 2012.769701] bcma-pci-bridge 0000:02:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[ 2012.769775] bcma: Core 0 found: ChipCommon (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x800, rev 0x25, class 0x0)
[ 2012.769808] bcma: Core 1 found: IEEE 802.11 (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x812, rev 0x1D, class 0x0)
[ 2012.769889] bcma: Core 2 found: PCIe (manuf 0x4BF, id 0x820, rev 0x13, class 0x0)
[ 2012.770175] bcma: PMU resource config unknown for device 0x4331
[ 2012.824527] bcma: Bus registered
[ 2012.831744] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4331 WLAN found (core revision 29)
[ 2013.371031] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
```

and to get the connection again every time i must entery that code in the step of reload driver.

How i can let the ubuntu see my wifi and wireless device automatically when i reboot my computer????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the code you enter:

```
sudo modprobe b43
```

If so, let's get the system to load the driver b43 automatically:

```
sudo su
echo b43 >> /etc/modules
exit
```

Comment: Perfectly.Every thing now is ok

Comment: I'm very glad it's working.